# Github: Can merge (rebase) modify the base branch from a PR?

Tags: git, github

The problem is that a database migration was merged into the `master` branch a while ago. For performance reasons we cannot us that migration in production. The migration script cannot remain in the history because it would be applied.

However, if I modify the migration script appropriately it would then break all of the commits after that point. Until the new commit that applies all the fixes. But this leave a bunch of broken commits in the history.

I would like to go back to the dozen or so commits, interactive rebase them one at a time with the individual fixes and apply the rest of the history on top. My real question, can this be done with a pull request?

This question is specific to GitHub, since I've heard it's rebase is a little different than a standard `git rebase`. Let's say I have this:

```
            E   F
            o---o
           /    ^ feature
A   B   C / D
o---o---o---o
            ^ master
```

If I rebase `feature` onto `master` it's fine (i.e. Merge PR with Rebase):

```
A   B   C   D   E'  F'
o---o---o---o---o---o
                    ^ master
                    ^ feature
```

However, what happens when I rebase commits on the `feature` branch that are older than the common ancestor (`B` holds the migration, `C` was removed, `D` relies on the migration changes):

```
    B'  D'  E   F
    o---o---o---o
   /            ^ feature
A / B   C   D
o---o---o---o
            ^ master
```

When merging `feature` onto `master`, will it do this?

```
A   B   C   D   B'  D'  E   F
o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o
                            ^ master
                            ^ feature
```

Effectively keeping the bad migration and no doubt causing some terrible conflicts. I would like to have this:

```
A   B'  D'  E   F
o---o---o---o---o
                ^ master
                ^ feature
```

Or is my only solution to rebase the `master` branch (carefully) and force push it back?

Comment: Why not just revert the change or fix it?  Why do you need to modify history to fix it?  I find rebase is often great on individual development branches, but causes a lot of issues on shared branches or the mainline.  To answer your question though, no, merging will not alter previous commits.  It only introduces new commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look at the question as asked:

> Can merge (rebase) modify the base branch from a [pull request]?

No.  Well, we need to be more precise; let's get back to this in a bit.  But in terms of what I think you mean, it's just "no".

> I would like to go back to the dozen or so commits, interactive rebase them one at a time with the individual fixes and apply the rest of the history on top. My real question, can this be done with a pull request?

No.

GitHub likes to obscure the details of Git (well, as much as any computer or web site can be said to have likes, dislikes, and feelings<sup>1</sup>), but there are a few absolute guarantees, including this one key item:  **No commit ever changes.**

Given that no commits change, how do we ever manage to remove bad commits or rewrite history?  For that matter, what does `git commit --amend` *do* when it seems to be changing a commit?  The answer is in your diagrams (so presumably you already know this): we can *copy* commits, by extracting the original commit, making some changes in the writable areas that Git has (the index and/or work-tree), and making *new* commits that are "just as good as" the originals, except that they're New And Improved.  And, of course, not the same as the originals, so they have different "true names": different hash IDs.

The way we *pretend* to change history is that we—all of us, both as Git users and as the computer running Git commands—have mutually agreed to a certain degree of madness and/or blindness, where in order to *find* some commits, we all start from a name, like `master` or `feature` or [`rumpelstiltskin/evil_or_misunderstood`](http://www.zoewrites.com/2013/04/19/evil-or-misunderstood/).  We turn that name into a hash ID, and use that to find our commits.  And it's these *names* that are changeable: if we slap the name atop a new series of commits, and forget that it used to be atop an old series of commits, why then, it's *as if* we changed history!

When you use the various GitHub clicky buttons to merge things, you get either:

- a true merge (`git merge --no-ff`), or
- a "squash" (`git merge --squash`), or
- a `git rebase` followed by a `git merge --ff-only`, with some safety checks applied.

To really understand these properly we also have to look at how pull requests work internally and in GitHub, but for simplicity, we can view this as: *A pull request sends whatever commits you have that they don't, into their repository, so that they can run the above commands.*  This is effectively the case, although I think GitHub sometimes plays various tricks with Git's internal "alternates" to avoid copying objects around.

In any case, though, *all they have to work with here is the commits you gave them*, which cannot be modified.  They can either copy them (`git rebase`), which copies all of them with some limited changes (GitHub's protection mechanism essentially makes there are no merge conflicts in any copy step, and no difference after the rebase than if they had done a merge) or make one new commit: a real merge commit, or a squash commit.

The final result will be that their branch name will point to some new commit, which will point to some previous commit(s), which will eventually lead back to their old branch-tip commit, and none of the interior commits will be different in any significant way from the ones in the original pull request.  Moreover, their old branch tip—the commit you labeled `D`—*will* be in the final chain:

```
A   B   C   D
o---o---o---o-...-o  <-- master
```

Regardless of how the picture looks after the `...` part, the part *before* the `...`—starting from `D` and working backwards to `A`—will be entirely unchanged.

> I would like to have this:
>
> ```
> A   B'  D'  E   F
> o---o---o---o---o
> ```

To get history rewritten, you must in general force-push.  You have to convince a Git instance—in this case, one on GitHub—to move `master` back to `A`.  Once that's happened, *then* you can add new commits, such as `B'` and so on, to the chain.  But this kind of rewind-and-regrow is not something Git "likes" (see footnote 1 again) to do: it must be forced upon it, using `git push -f` or `git reset`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers; they hate that.

Answer (score 0):

For your title's question, no a Pull Request cannot rebase.

For your underlying issue, I'd recommend using `git revert` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)). It will create a new commit that undoes everything the original, specified commit did.

For example, if your undesired migration was added via commit `123abc`, you would run

```
git revert 123abc
```

A new commit would be created effectively ctrl+z-ing all changes made in commit `123abc`.